# Check for negative numbers in Jquery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery-validate

I am trying to set-up the [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and one of my inputs requires a number within the range of -121 and -123.

I have tried using the range() method :

```
     $("#myform").validate({
       rules: {
         field: {
          required: true,
          range: [-121, -123]
        }
       }
      });
```

However it doesn't allow any numbers to validate. I have tried using max/min as well but they too don't seem to work on negative numbers. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the smaller number need to be first? If so, you want `range: [-123, -121]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod('inputClassName',
    function (value) { 
        return (Number(value) >= -123 && Number(value) <= -121);
    }, 'Enter a number between -121 and -123');
```

You could add this custom validator method, just replace the inputClassName

Comment: Thanks Brian but mblase75 answer works as well. I think I will probably need to create some custom method later so your answer will still come in handy.